# Convert AJAX date to Javascript date for use with ng-model

Tags: json, angularjs, momentjs

I am using $http.get in a service in to fetch JSON data. One of my object properties in the returned JSON is a date which is not being parsed by AngularJS. I need to bind this property to a date field and I am currently working around it by manually converting the JSON string to a javascript date after fetching the AJAX data as shown below

```
app.service('MainService', function(){
  var self = this;
  self.jsonDate = null;
  self.parsedDate = null;

  // this function will get JSON data from an API in production
  self.getData = function(){
    var jsonData = "2014-06-13T16:00:00";

    // Angular does not convert my JSON data properties into dates
    self.jsonDate = jsonData;

    // I can work around this by forcing my dates to be parsed
    self.parsedDate = moment(jsonData).toDate();
  }
});
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? I built a filter that converts a string to a date

```
app.filter('stringToDate', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (!input)
            return null;

        var date = moment(input);
        return date.isValid() ? date.toDate() : null;
    };
});
```

The filter works great if I use it as shown below

```
<span ng-bind="service.jsonDate | stringToDate | date:'MM/dd/yy'"></span>
```

but it does not work if I try to use it with ng-model as shown below

```
<input type="date" ng-model="service.jsonDate | stringToDate"/>
```

Can a filter be used with ng-model or do I need to stick with manually converting properties to dates? I have a plunker here that demonstrates my current code

http://plnkr.co/edit/pVaDbjIjtnKaYqrjAd0D?p=preview

Comment: Updated answer with custom directive option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Plunker Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/48MeXpdgg56oOZGlXE8G?p=preview)

There are few ways you can do this:

1. Use the filter in ng-init to initialize a scope variable, then bind the ng-model to the scope variable.

   ```
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="mydate = (service.jsonDate | stringToDate)">
       <label>Raw JSON Date</label>
       <input type="date" data-ng-model="service.jsonDate"/><br/><br/>

       <label>Parsed JSON date</label>
       <input type="date" data-ng-model="mydate"/>
    </body>
   ```
2. Use the `$filter` service to manually invoke the `stringToDate` filter in your controller:

   ```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, MainService) {
       $scope.service = MainService;

       // fetch data from service
       $scope.service.getData();

       $scope.parsedDate = $filter('stringToDate')(MainService.jsonDate);

   });
   ```

   And then bind the variable to your `ng-model`:

   ```
   <input type="date" data-ng-model="parsedDate"/>
   ```

   **[EDIT]**
3. Use a [custom directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/48MeXpdgg56oOZGlXE8G?p=preview) which relies on an ng-model that is raw JSON. Add a formatter to convert the model to a date string; and a parser to convert the date string back to the model.  The advantage of this approach is that the two-way model binding is maintained.  When you update the text box with a valid date string, it automatically updates the raw JSON model (and vice versa).

In the plunker example, try entering a valid date string, and notice how the model automatically changes.

**Directive:**

```
   app.directive('jsonDate', function($filter) {
      return  {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

             //format text going to user (model to view)
             ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                var date = $filter('stringToDate')(value);
                return date.toString();
             });

             //format text from the user (view to model)
             ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                var date = new Date(value);
                if (!isNaN( date.getTime())) { 
                   return moment(date).format();
                }
             });
         }
     }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="date" data-ng-model="service.jsonDate" json-date/>
```

This last example allows you to bind an ngModel to a json date string and have it display a formatted date.  When the user enters a valid formatted date, it automatically updates the json date string model that its bound to

Comment: Thanks for elaborated answer. one query though, I am also trying example 3 from last many hours, but it is not working, after html get loaded it does not show date. I visited your plunker, and it is also not showing date anymore.

Comment: On your plunker, when .html page loaded on browser, I am expecting it to show the date, but why it is not the case?